# Laravel 6.x route: no query results found

Tags: php, laravel

I encountered a mysterious error. I defined a route the following:

```php
Route::get("/customers/alla", "Customer\CustomerController@loadAllCustomers")->name("customers.all");
```

When I call the function I get the following error: `No query results for model [App\Models\Customer] alla`

In `loadAllCustomers()` I only return `test` for testing. But nothing appears.

If I change the url to `/customers/all` then the error changes also to `all` from `alla`.

xDebug does not trigger in the function.

What does laravel trying to do there?

I also cleared the route cache but it won't changed anything

My "whole" routes.php looks like this:

```php
Route::get("/customers", "Customer\CustomerController@index")->name("customer.index");
    Route::get("/customers/{id}", "Customer\CustomerController@show")->name("customer.show");
    Route::get("/customers/alla", "Customer\CustomerController@loadAllCustomers")->name("customers.all");
    Route::post("/customers/store", "Customer\CustomerController@store")->name("customer.save");
    Route::post("/customers/{id}", "Customer\CustomerController@update")->name("customer.update");
    Route::get("/customers/{id}/delete", "Customer\CustomerController@delete")->name("customer.delete");
    Route::post("/customers/{id}/loadCustomerContactPersons", "Customer\CustomerController@loadCustomerContactPersons")->name("customer.contactPerson.all");
    Route::post("/customers/{id}/contactPerson", "Customer\CustomerController@createContactPerson")->name("customer.contactPerson.create");
    Route::get("/customer/{id}/contactPerson/{contactPersonId}", "Customer\CustomerController@getContactPerson")->name("customer.contactPerson.get");
    Route::put("/customer/{id}/contactPerson/{contactPersonId}", "Customer\CustomerController@updateContactPerson")->name("customer.contactPerson.update");
    Route::post("/customers/{id}/loadCustomerAddresses", "Customer\CustomerController@loadCustomerAddresses")->name("customer.customerAddress.all");
    Route::post("/customers/{id}/CustomerPayment/save", "Customer\CustomerController@saveCustomerPayment")->name("customer.customerPayment.save");
    Route::post("/customers/{id}/customerAddress", "Customer\CustomerController@createCustomerAddress")->name("customer.customerAddress.create");
    Route::get("/customers/{id}/deleteCustomerAddress/{addressId}", "Customer\CustomerController@deleteCustomerAddress")->name("customer.customerAddress.delete");
    Route::get("/customers/{id}/deleteContactPerson/{contactPersonId}", "Customer\CustomerController@deleteContactPerson")->name("customer.contactPerson.delete");
```

Comment: can you i see your file route?

Comment: @sokhai the whole?

Comment: All the routes that start with `/customers/`, in the order that they are in the route file

Comment: done, I tried to check if its related to duplicates but could found any duplicates.

Comment: Move you "/customers/alla" to first it will work

Comment: @sokhai ok thanks it work, but why does it behave like this?

Comment: Wildcards have to go last when using similar routes. When the router loads, it goes through the routes in order. If it finds an exact match, it will use that directive. But when it hits a wildcard, it will match anything that has not yet been matched.

Comment: @Gamestar please take a look at my answer.

Comment: already answer by @aynber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two first routes have the same pattern. Laravel's route dispatcher launches the first route that matches, so when you visit `/customers/alla`, it actually launches `/customers/{id}` with `$id = "alla"`. There are no customers with their ID being equal to `"alla"`, right?

Comment: Ah thats why. If I think deeper its quite logical but as a beginner its not that obvious ^^. Thanks!